# Занести цифры числа в массив

Tags: java

Я хочу занести цифры числа в массив, но на деле мой цикл не делает этого. Он вносит максимум 4 цифры. В чем дело?

```
ArrayList digits = new ArrayList();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter first number");
int firstnum = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter second number");
int secondnum = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter number system (10 - max)");
int NS = in.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i <= (Integer.toString(firstnum)).length(); i++) {
    digits.add(firstnum%10);
    firstnum = firstnum/10;
    System.out.println(digits);
}

System.out.println(digits);
```

Comment: Причем стоит отметить, что длина (Integer.toString(firstnum)).length() совпадает с длинной числа

Comment: в этой строчке `(Integer.toString(firstnum)).length()` вы число конвертируете в строку и получаете длину строки. Например, для числа `12345`, строка будет `"12345"`, длина строки будет `5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка, чья длина используется в условии цикла, - уменьшается на каждой итерации.

```
String firstnumStr = Integer.toString(firstnum);
for (int i = 0; i < firstnumStr.length(); i++) {
  ...
```

или просто

```
while (firstnum > 0) {
```

Comment: Да, это помогло. Но разве у меня не написано то же самое? В чем подвох?)

Comment: @shadow1337 В Вашем коде - "Строка, чья длина используется в условии цикла, - уменьшается на каждой итерации."