# Не могу добавить объект в массив через push

Tags: javascript

Создаю пользователя через конструктор User, но потом когда хочу добавить его в массив через push мне выводит Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

В чем ошибка?

UPD: понял, что дело в том, что отдельная функция UsersList.add как бы не видит массив this.users (или я не прав?)

Но как тогда сделать отдельную функцию, чтобы он видел этот массив?

```
function User(firstName, lastName, regDate) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.regDate = regDate;

}


function UserList() {
    this.users = [];
}

UserList.add = function (justUser) {
    console.log(justUser);
    this.users.push(justUser);
}

let start = function () {
    while (true) {
        let fullName = prompt('Your name and surname ?');

        if (fullName === null) break;

        let fullNameArr = fullName.split(' ');
        // console.log(fullNameArr);
        let firstName = fullNameArr[0];
        let lastName = fullNameArr[1];
        let d = new Date();
        var newUser = new User(firstName, lastName, d);
        UserList.add(newUser);


    }


}
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051474/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2

Comment: @Igor на тот момент еще не разбирался насчет галочки) спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function UserList() {
    this.users = [];
}

UserList.prototype.add = function (justUser) {
    console.log(justUser);
    this.users.push(justUser);
}

var userList = new UserList();


    ...
    userList.add(newUser);
```

Comment: мне теперь пишет UserList.add is not a function

Comment: @shadow1337 Зато  `userList.add` - is a function.